# Possible to run cardano-node on marlowe pioneer testnet using docker-compose

Tags: marlowe-pioneer-program

I wanted to run the cardano-node, marlowe pioneer testnet on Ubuntu using docker.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/master/docker-compose.yml
NETWORK=???????? docker-compose up -d
```

Anyone know what **NETWORK** we can use to access the pioneer testnet ?
I only know mainnet, testnet
this could imply that we use some sort of **private** testnet ?

*sidenote:*
*I would like to know if we can do all these course material using mainnet too perhaps,

that would lean close towards the real use of smart-contracts deployment and utilization ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of this marlowe pioneer program this question is irrelevant.
There is a nix-shell environment that you can use instead.

setup your Ubuntu OS

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install curl xz-utils -y

sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon
nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m"
nix-env --version

sudo vi /etc/nix/nix.conf
# add the following content to the end of the file and save

substituters = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=
experimental-features = nix-command flakes
allow-import-from-derivation = true

sudo systemctl restart nix-daemon.service
```

download and startup nix-shell with marlowe tools

```
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano.git
cd marlowe-cardano
git checkout marlowe-pioneers
nix-shell
start-marlowe-run
```

Notice you now have a tmux multiple windows system syncing, wait for it to finish

You can find the node.socket with

```
sudo find / -name '*node.socket'
```

then setup with

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/tmp/node.socket
export CARDANO_TESTNET_MAGIC=1567
```

My advice is that the docker-compose solution is only working for a specific set of networks only: mainnet or testnet
These only include cardano-cli and cardano-wallet

Then you can use the binary executable files from the proper nix-shell paths that can be found here:

```
sudo find /nix/store -wholename '*/bin/cardano-cli'
sudo find /nix/store -wholename '*/bin/marlowe-cli'
sudo find /nix/store -wholename '*/bin/cardano-wallet'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for `marlowe-pioneers` (reference [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/iohk-nix/blob/edb2d2df2ebe42bbdf03a0711115cf6213c9d366/release.nix#L58) ).
I am not a big fan of docker/nix myself (for not so "micro" services) - so not testing it out beforehand, but that should be the right ID. If you'd want to look at configs/genesis/topology files yourself, you can find them [here](http://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/iohk-nix/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/index.html).

Comment: owh interesting  
I tried but get this  

```NETWORK=marlowe-pioneers docker-compose up -d
service "cardano-node" refers to undefined volume node-marlowe-pioneers-db: invalid compose project```
owh ok I see the docker compose file is not including the marlowe-pioneers db

Comment: Ye - shouldn't be too difficult to customise to other networks, can update those configs/genesis mounts seperately

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to edit the code below for it to work perhaps
[**original docker-compose from github**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/master/docker-compose.yml) copied below for editing

(problem is that the docker image does not have the config file)

[**STATUS**: editing, not yet working]

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  cardano-node:
    image: inputoutput/cardano-node:1.34.1
    environment:
      NETWORK:
    volumes:
      - node-${NETWORK}-db:/data
      - node-ipc:/ipc
    restart: on-failure
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        compress: "true"
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: "50m"

  cardano-wallet:
    image: inputoutput/cardano-wallet:2022.5.27
    volumes:
      - wallet-${NETWORK}-db:/wallet-db
      - node-ipc:/ipc
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    entrypoint: []
    command: bash -c "
        ([[ $$NETWORK == \"mainnet\" ]] && $$CMD --mainnet) ||
        ([[ $$NETWORK == \"marlowe-pioneers\" ]] && $$CMD --testnet /config/${NETWORK}/marlowe-pioneers-byron-genesis.json) ||
        ($$CMD --testnet /config/${NETWORK}/genesis-byron.json)
      "
    environment:
      CMD: "cardano-wallet serve --node-socket /ipc/node.socket --database /wallet-db --listen-address 0.0.0.0"
      NETWORK:
    restart: on-failure
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        compress: "true"
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: "50m"

volumes:
  node-mainnet-db:
  node-testnet-db:
  node-alonzo-purple-db:
  node-marlowe-pioneers-db:
  wallet-mainnet-db:
  wallet-testnet-db:
  wallet-alonzo-purple-db:
  wallet-marlowe-pioneers-db:
  node-ipc:
  node-config:
```

Comment: cardano-cardano-node-1    | [Error] Managed configuration for network marlowe-pioneers does not exist

Comment: cardano-cardano-wallet-1  | [cardano-wallet.main:Error:4] [2022-06-07 12:25:19.71 UTC] Failed to parse Byron genesis configuration. You may want to check the filepath given via --genesis and make sure it points to a  valid JSON Byron genesis file. The genesis file must be Byron, not Shelley as it used to feed the wallet with the initial blockchain parameters. Here's (perhaps) some helpful hint: GenesisDataIOError /config/marlowe-pioneers/genesis-byron.json: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Comment: Hello, Due to the nature of StackExchange (posting possible answers to questions and fixes to the problem) the current state of your response it not suitable to this site. Its more of a github issue post conversation or a blog type post. I would suggest submitting it to one of those sites or changing it to highlight that the reason you don't belive its possible is the lack of the config file. Also if this is made during the time your still working on an answer please finish testing things locally and update the post to include all the result and be written in the form of an direct answer.

Comment: I agree, I will think about cleaning up this question, since I have been playing with nix-shell instead, you can only use this docker-compose file for mainnet and public testnet nothing else. And trying to get the marlowe-pioneer node running fails because the topology file has a wrong relay hostname.
https://hydra.iohk.io/build/14528927/download/1/index.html  
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3001:3001 --volume $PWD/configuration:/configuration inputoutput/cardano-node run --topology /configuration/marlowe-pioneers-topology.json --config /configuration/marlowe-pioneers-config.json

Answer (score 0):

NETWORK=???

Get's translated, to the "magic-id" parameter in the cardano-cli.

The number you are looking for is `1567`

And we will look at it in more detail in Lecture 7 "marlowe-cli"

Comment: Marlowe CLI requires access to a Cardano node,
I don't want to use Daedalus but use a docker-compose hosted cardano-node and cardano-wallet on mainnet and marlowe-pioneer testnet in order to manipulate transactions and wallets using python. It works on python for the mainnet, but I don't know how to get it to work on any other testnet ?
Your response as far as setting up a mart contract is probably correct but not in line with my current problem

Comment: [myVM01:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Warning:53] [2022-06-08 17:03:28.32 UTC] Domain: "relays.marlowe-pioneers.dev.cardano.org" Failed to start all required subscriptions
[myVM01:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Debug:53] [2022-06-08 17:03:29.33 UTC] Domain: "relays.marlowe-pioneers.dev.cardano.org" Restarting Subscription after 1.26569077s desired valency 2 current valency 0
[myVM01:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Debug:53] [2022-06-08 17:03:38.06 UTC] Domain: "relays.marlowe-pioneers.dev.cardano.org" Starting Subscription Worker, valency 2